# rustc "error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1" when trying to call C function from Rust

Tags: c, rust, linker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying a very simple program that calls a C function from Rust, following [this website](https://liufuyang.github.io/2020/02/02/call-c-in-rust.html).
It's just making an object file from C code using `clang -c`, then building and linking using `rustc`.

However, in my WSL environment, a linking error happens when using `rustc`.
Are there any ways to solve this error?

```bash
$ clang doubler.c -c
$ rustc main.rs -l doubler.o -L .
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
  |
  = note: "cc" "-m64" "/tmp/rustcl2ZRSZ/symbols.o" "main.main.e9c37ed3-cgu.0.rcgu.o" "main.main.e9c37ed3-cgu.1.rcgu.o" "main.main.e9c37ed3-cgu.2.rcgu.o" "main.main.e9c37ed3-cgu.3.rcgu.o" "main.main.e9c37ed3-cgu.4.rcgu.o" "main.main.e9c37ed3-cgu.5.rcgu.o" "main.main.e9c37ed3-cgu.6.rcgu.o" "main.main.e9c37ed3-cgu.7.rcgu.o" "main.54dxu6qjn1ilt3e4.rcgu.o" "-Wl,--as-needed" "-L" "." "-L" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-ldoubler.o" "-Wl,--start-group" "-Wl,-Bstatic" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd-8f1929c73c3f8167.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libpanic_unwind-e359d865975ccf21.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libobject-b886fd10c5a7c7c0.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libmemchr-9d7c322d48daa475.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libaddr2line-08ae1606a951cabe.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libgimli-682a81c4b2133b72.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_demangle-a73b3512c88de071.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libstd_detect-7b5ec4c918d9f957.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libhashbrown-65c63cf3af0af657.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libminiz_oxide-4a53f0a2785abc6a.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libadler-868e2d515c28d027.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_alloc-394ad2d73aede76a.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libunwind-19c77e4dc3dcb87e.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcfg_if-fb44a42088c9369a.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liblibc-61a7402e61a5b0e0.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/liballoc-63f8356c87a0d0e8.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/librustc_std_workspace_core-a506e577d917828c.rlib" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcore-fc1fb63210fdafad.rlib" "-Wl,--end-group" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/libcompiler_builtins-c21be34a5cae8449.rlib" "-Wl,-Bdynamic" "-lgcc_s" "-lutil" "-lrt" "-lpthread" "-lm" "-ldl" "-lc" "-Wl,--eh-frame-hdr" "-Wl,-znoexecstack" "-L" "/home/yoshikuni/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib" "-o" "main" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs"
  = note: /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ldoubler.o
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          

error: aborting due to previous error
```

I'm using WSL2 on Windows 11, Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, and rustc 1.63.0.
Since this same command works on my Mac somehow, this may be related to WSL environment.

These are source codes that I want to build:

```c
// doubler.h
const int FACTOR = 2;

int doubler(int x);
```

```c
// doubler.c
#include "doubler.h"
extern const int FACTOR;

int doubler(int x)
{
    return x * FACTOR;
}
```

```rust
// main.rs
extern "C" {
    fn doubler(x: i32) -> i32;
}

fn main() {
    unsafe {
        println!("{}", doubler(1));
    }
}
```

Comment: The option `-l` is for linking with a *library*, not an object file. For an object file just list it as you do with your source file.

Comment: Like this?
`$ rustc main.rs doubler.o`

Then this error happens:
error: multiple input filenames provided (first two filenames are `main.rs` and `doubler.o`)

Comment: Actually it doesn't seem to be possible to link directly with object files. You either need to create an actual library of your object file (I don't know if that's possible to link with either) or use a Rust build script as describe [here](https://aeshirey.github.io/code/2020/06/13/simple-c-library-with-rust.html).

Comment: However, the exact same commands (`$ clang doubler.c -c` and `$ rustc main.rs -l doubler.o -L .`) works in my Mac environment. So I guess it's somewhere in WSL or Ubuntu or rustc for linux)